# Почему проверка наличия элемента во множестве и в списокe проходит за разное время?

Tags: python

Почему проверка наличия элемента во множестве и в списокe проходит за разное время?

Comment: Да. В списке проверка требует время пропорциональное длине списка. В множестве проверка требует постоянного времени.

Comment: в питоне нет массивов же.

Comment: Я имел ввиду список, не привык пока.

Comment: А как вообще работает проверка списка и множества?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В множестве как и в словаре проверка производится по хэшу элемента (ключа для словаря), который хитрым образом преобразуется в адрес элемента в памяти. На случай если происходит коллизия,  и у разных элементов оказывается одинаковый хэш, есть механизм разрешения коллизий. В простейшем случае - это список элементов с одинаковым хэшем, в котором дальше идёт поиск. В целом при небольшом числе коллизий поиск во множестве и в словаре по ключу имеет сложность О(1).
А вот при поиске в списке нужно последовательно перебрать его элементы, пока не найдётся нужный, это уже сложность О(n).

Answer (score 2):

потому что в списке (массиве), чтобы проверить наличие  элемента надо просмотреть все (!!!) элементы, т.е. потратить O(n) времени (линейное время)

а в множестве, чтобы чтобы понять индекс элемента в котором хранится элемент можно вычислить хэш от элемента

```
index = hash(value)
```

в этом случае поиск элемента будет занимать константное время O(1)

Comment: В питоне проверка наличия в set делается за амортизированное константное время, а не log. Читайте https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: да, потом вспомнил - там index = func(N)

Comment: Ну так перепишите ответ. Нет никакого поиска, есть индекс по хэшу плюс разрешение коллизий. В целом можно считать, что О(1) для множества.